# How to cleanly create typesafe enum argument

Tags: c++, type-safety

I want to create a function "void set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(char c)". This is not the actual name of the function but it explains its' intent.

The reason why I want this to be done at compile time is because I want to create a class to encapsulate the TicTacToe system so that the system can override start player explicitly before the game starts without rebuilding the class.

Here's a naive convoluted sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class TTCSystem
{
public:
    static const int PLAYERX = 1;
    static const int PLAYERO = 2;

    void set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(char c);
private:
    int start_player;    
};

void TTCSystem::set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(char c)
{
    if (c == 'x' || c == 'X') {
        this->start_player = PLAYERX;
    } else if (c == 'o' || c == 'O') {
        this->start_player = PLAYERO;
    } else {
        std::cout << "PANICING AS HARD AS I CAN" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TTCSystem ttcs;
    ttcs.set_tic_tac_toe_start_player('9');

    return 0;
}
```

The function is to be used to override the default player who goes in the tic tac toe game, 'X' or 'O'.

The issue is that any char can be passed, whereas only want to accept 
{'x', 'X', 'o', 'O'}.

I could create an enum, but I am afraid that enum won't enforce the typechecking.

I could use a class to invent an enum type, or exploit inheritance but if I even go that route, I don't want to reinvent the wheel and do a horrible job at it.

Is there a more universal/elegant/simple solution to creating a typesafe enum?

I am looking for something that ensures that the input to set_tic_tac_toe_start_player is checked at compile time that the player selected to go first is a valid player(one of the 4 inputs).

[EDIT] Thanks Jonathan for the suggestion, I've posted the solution below.

Comment: Why checking at compile time ? You never use this function at run time ?

Comment: You have a point. I can set that as constant, I just wanted a clean programmer's override. Let me rephrase the question.

Comment: I added a small naive code to demonstrate the general idea of what I want to do. It's not the cleanest isolated demo but I think it kinda makes sense.

@Shumush I check at compile time so that I provide a simple programmer interface to manipulate the tic tac toe system without rebuilding the class.

Comment: `class TTCSystem { enum Player { PlayerX, PlayerY }; void set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(Player p) { start_player = p; } ... };` What's the problem? The only valid values of the enumeration type are `PlayerX` and `PlayerY` (i.e. 0 and 1). Any other values are outside the range of values of the type. In any case, you can just do `if (start_player == PlayerX) ... else ...` so that you treat any non-zero value as `PlayerY`

Comment: I forgot I could do that. I thought I had to give it an integer and it could fall out of bounds. That works unless I am missing some way to pass something invalid into it. 

I posted the solution I drafted, hopefully I didn't butcher your intent too much.

Comment: @Dmitry, Jonathan is right, you can treat any invalid values as playerX or playerO (the one you prefer) and print a little message to tell the user that he won't get the player he wanted.

If you reaaaaaaaally want to check at compile time, you could create a template function which take a char for template argument, and use [std::enable_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/) to only allow the creation of the functions `start<'x'>()`, `start<'o'>()`, `start<'X'>()`, or `start<'O'>()`

sorry for the long time to answer ^^

Comment: @Shumush That seems to make the interface too painful to use. I wanted to try to find a solution to this which is easy to use and hard to misuse.

Comment: @Dmitry Then use Jonathan's method. Be careful though, enums are not type-safe, you can still do `static_cast<Player>(3)` and pass a wrong value, but your function `TTCSystem::get_tic_tac_toe_start_player()` would return `'O'` then, so it's fine.

Comment: If you want type-safe enums why don't you use type-safe enums?

Comment: @PreferenceBean The solution Jonathan provided works. I checked it against forcing 9 as a parameter and compiler rejects it. It seems difficult enough to bypass this unintentionally now. I provided the non-compiling code to demonstrate it will reject it.

Comment: This isn't a forum. The people above should have posted answers and you should have accepted one of them. Now we have a mess of comment-based discussion and you felt the only thing you could do was to edit "[Solved]" into the title. Folks, learn to Stack Exchange!!!

Comment: @PreferenceBean You're right but none of them posted an answer and I can't accept a comment and now I feel silly and do what I can... I understand it's not a comment but I don't want to write an answer myself now that Jonathan did it... I guess ill do it anyway. Sorry, still learning all these situations, it takes a while.

Comment: I think you did the right thing :)

Comment: Use an `enum class`, then it cannot be circumvented without using a cast

Comment: @M.M enum class? Like "enum class Player{PlayerX, PlayerO};"? I'm not familar with this convention :|

Comment: Oh it seems like a c++11 feature that stops scope conflict. I am not sure I need this since PlayerX, PlayerO are exclusively used as Player enum, and nothing else in the scope will cause conflict in them. It is nice to know though, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jonathan. Here is the solution I came up with based on your response.

This part is only there to demonstrate the rejection of invalid argument, remove it to see it compile properly.

```
    ttcs.set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(9);
    std::cout << "player: " 
              << ttcs.get_tic_tac_toe_start_player() 
              << std::endl;
```

Below is the solution

```
#include <iostream>

class TTCSystem
{
public:
    enum Player {PlayerX, PlayerO};

    void set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(Player p);
    char get_tic_tac_toe_start_player();

private:
    Player start_player;    
};

void TTCSystem::set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(Player p)
{
    this->start_player = p;
}

char TTCSystem::get_tic_tac_toe_start_player()
{
    return ((start_player == PlayerX) ? 'X' : 'O');
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TTCSystem ttcs;
    ttcs.set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(TTCSystem::PlayerX);
    std::cout << "player: " 
              << ttcs.get_tic_tac_toe_start_player() 
              << std::endl;

    ttcs.set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(TTCSystem::PlayerO);
    std::cout << "player: " 
              << ttcs.get_tic_tac_toe_start_player() 
              << std::endl;

    ttcs.set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(TTCSystem::PlayerX);
    std::cout << "player: " 
              << ttcs.get_tic_tac_toe_start_player() 
              << std::endl;

    ttcs.set_tic_tac_toe_start_player(9);
    std::cout << "player: " 
              << ttcs.get_tic_tac_toe_start_player() 
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```